# How do you lock a process in memory and not let it page swap?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, java

How do I keep a Windows Tomcat 6 service process from having so many page faults? It has 9M faults. I have plenty of memory and want to keep the entire JVM in RAM and keep it from swapping, to make it faster. The Tomcat service is 8GB and the computer has 24GB RAM. The server is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

Here is screenshot of TaskManager: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMxwb.png

[image: task manager]

Comment: I don't know anything that will prevent this. Maybe you can make a RAM Disk for your swapfile

Comment: Is something actually wrong? Or are you just looking for ways to take flexibility away from the operating system? (Even though it has much more information than you do about how best to use memory.)

Comment: Yes, I want to take flexibility from the OS. The whole server is dedicated to this web service process. I want it to run faster. I want anything else that needs too much RAM to fail.

Comment: @Chloe: Unfortunately, that won't work. Instead of failing, it will cause the server to squeeze its cache, increasing the I/O load on the server and slowing it down. You cannot fix something that is not broken, but you can make it very, very fragile.

Answer (score 1):

If those are mostly soft faults, you probably don't have a problem.

Are they hard or soft faults? What are the perfmon numbers for both?  Have you noticed any actual problems, or are you just pre-emptively trying to optimize?

Comment: Preemptive. I don't know if hard/soft. I have not run perfmon in a while. Yes, there are many problems. http://i.imgur.com/9DyHU.png

Comment: As I said : if those are mostly soft faults, *you don't have a problem* , unless you have any other evidence of actual problems. I'm not seeing you present any other problems here. It will take you a couple of minutes to set up perfmon to show the difference between soft and hard faults for this process. Task Manager is a starting point, but it's a fairly blunt instrument.